# Is plain orthographic transciption of speech recordings adequate for corpus creation?

Tags: orthography, corpora, transcription, corpus-linguistics

NOTE: I am not a linguist, but my interest is in the Natural Language Processing (NLP) field.

I am doing a research which is focused only on gathering new or distinct words on a recently described language. The original lexicon contains only about 1500 words, so my goal is to increase its size by using NLP methods.

The language that I am studying don't have a standard orthography, however, IPA transcription is not feasible based on my constraints, so I am focusing on employing native speakers to transcribe speech recordings based on their abilities. However is there a standard convention to be followed whenever transcribing a language orthographically other than just typing the letters that best represent the utterances?

I found a work by Bailey (2008), however I haven't traced what resource is her transcription convention was based after. Also, when transcribing, are we allowed to use punctations  or symbols (with as-is meanings) like when we traditionally write text like commas, exclamation/question marks, periods?

**Transcription Conventions**

| notation | meaning |
| --- | --- |
| (?) | talk too obscure to transcribe. |
| Hhhhh | audible out-breath |
| .hhh | in-breath |
| [ | overlapping talk begins |
| ] | overlapping talk ends |
| (.) | silence, less than half a second |
| (..) | silence, less than one second |
| (2.8) | silence measured in 10ths of a second |
| :::: | lengthening of a sound |
| Becau- | cut off, interruption of a sound |
| _he_ says. | Emphasis *(this is underline, not underscores)* |
| = no | silence at all between sounds |
| LOUD | sounds |
| ? | rising intonation |
| (left hand on neck) | body conduct |

[notes, comments]

Bailey, J. (2008). First steps in qualitative data analysis: Transcribing. Family Practice, 25(2), 127–131. https://doi.org/10.1093/fampra/cmn003

Comment: What does "typing the letters that best represent the utterances" mean if you don't have an orthography and don't want to use a phonetic transcription?

Comment: sir @Draconis I was seeking expert inputs on how a language without a standard orthography can still have a structured approach (like Bailey) that the native speakers can use while transcribing the audio recordings. Or is Bailey's method sufficient?

Comment: I mean it as a legitimate question. You'll need some consistent way to transcribe the audio, or else you'll end up with the same word written a dozen different ways, which isn't good for a corpus. Whether that's a standard orthography, or a phonemic transcription, or something else doesn't really matter, but you need something. So—do you have something like that, or is that what you're asking about?

Comment: I understand your point now, also based on Davidson, the transcription methods and perspectives are diverse. Proposing a standard orthography is outside of my expertise (or the lack thereof), but it may be a good start for future researchers to scrutinize and improve on. You've clarified my month-long agony in just 2 hours, lol! (due to the challenges in communication and common schedule with my resource persons)

Davidson, C. (2009). Transcription: Imperatives for Qualitative Research. International Journal of Qualitative Methods, 8, 35–62. https://doi.org/10.1177/160940690900800206